# how to make a video stream bot for discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a bot with discord.py that can stream videos from mp4 into a voice channel. Is it possible? and if it is possible how would I be able to do it (and sorry if this is a stupid question i am a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it isn't possible, you can only stream audio.